# I need to make rows and columns in angular 6 using recursion in which row can columns and columns have any numbers of row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6-json-schema-form

I tried using making it using dynamic HTML but I unable to call click event in dynamic HTML.

**This is what is tried by myself**

```
my .ts file
htmlgrid:any;
jsonData:any;
 ngOnInit(){

this.htmlgrid= this.parse(this.jsonData)

}




createRow (r) {
    return '<div  style="background-color : ' + r.color + '" class="row">' +
      (r.text ? r.text : '') + this.parse(r) + '</div>';
  }
  createColumn (c) {
    return '<div style="background - color: red;" class="col-md-' + 6 + ' test">' +
      (c.text ? c.text : '') + this.parse(c) + '<img  click="hell();"  src = "../../../../assets/img/collection.jpg" style = "height: 100px; width:auto;" />' + '</div>';
  }
  parse (s) {
    let S = '';
    if (s.rows) {
      for (let i in s.rows) {
        console.log(s.rows[ i ], 'i of data');
        S += this.createRow(s.rows[ i ]);
      }
    }
    if (s.columns) {
      for (let i in s.columns) {
        S += this.createColumn(s.columns[ i ]);
      }
    }
    console.log(S, 'value of s');
    return S;
  }
```

**My.html file**

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

this type of JSON is used for making rows and columns,we also have identifiers and row-column checks in our JSON. Please help I got stuck here so bad,
i need to make grid of row and columns on the basis of below json

```
this.jsonData={
"rows":[ 
         { 
            "columns":[ 
               { 
                  "identifier":"c1",
                  "hasRows":false,
                   "cashBack":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "title":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "images":{ 
                     "leafBanner":{ 
                        "url":"",
                        "bannerName":"",
                        "bannerType":"",
                        "bannerTarget":""
                     },
                     "listPageBanner":{ 
                        "image":"",
                        "2X":{ 
                           "height":"200px",
                           "width":"400px"
                        },
                        "3X":{ 
                           "height":"300px",
                           "width":"600px"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "height":"50",
                  "width":"50"
               },
               { 
                  "identifier":"c2",
                  "hasRows":false,
                  "cashBack":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "title":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "images":{ 
                     "leafBanner":{ 
                        "url":"",
                        "bannerName":"",
                        "bannerType":"",
                        "bannerTarget":""
                     },
                     "listPageBanner":{ 
                        "image":"",
                        "2X":{ 
                           "height":"200px",
                           "width":"400px"
                        },
                        "3X":{ 
                           "height":"300px",
                           "width":"600px"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "height":"50",
                  "width":"50"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "columns":[ 
               { 
                  "identifier":"c3",
                  "hasRows":false,
                   "cashBack":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "title":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "images":{ 
                     "leafBanner":{ 
                        "url":"",
                        "bannerName":"",
                        "bannerType":"",
                        "bannerTarget":""
                     },
                     "listPageBanner":{ 
                        "image":"",
                        "2X":{ 
                           "height":"200px",
                           "width":"400px"
                        },
                        "3X":{ 
                           "height":"300px",
                           "width":"600px"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "height":"33",
                  "width":"33"
               },
               { 
                  "identifier":"c4",
                  "hasRows":false,
                   "cashBack":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "title":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "images":{ 
                     "leafBanner":{ 
                        "url":"",
                        "bannerName":"",
                        "bannerType":"",
                        "bannerTarget":""
                     },
                     "listPageBanner":{ 
                        "image":"",
                        "2X":{ 
                           "height":"200px",
                           "width":"400px"
                        },
                        "3X":{ 
                           "height":"300px",
                           "width":"600px"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "height":"33",
                  "width":"33"
               },
               { 
                  "identifier":"c5",
                  "hasRows":false,
                   "cashBack":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "title":{ 
                     "text":""
                  },
                  "images":{ 
                     "leafBanner":{ 
                        "url":"",
                        "bannerName":"",
                        "bannerType":"",
                        "bannerTarget":""
                     },
                     "listPageBanner":{ 
                        "image":"",
                        "2X":{ 
                           "height":"200px",
                           "width":"400px"
                        },
                        "3X":{ 
                           "height":"300px",
                           "width":"600px"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "height":"33",
                  "width":"33"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
}
```

Comment: without looking at code no one could help you out. You can put a minimal working demo even w/o css focusing on the issue in hand maybe try a stackblitz to reproduce the problem

Comment: @joyBlanks i updated the code , please have a look

Comment: Can you create this in stackblitz?

Comment: and just to tell you angular people have tried hard so we do not have to create html the template like you are creating as in jQuery/javascript world its a framework not library or something. you can have component recursive calling to same component

Comment: Try the following stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1p1ap

Comment: the above link its working fine for me whats the issue you are facing generating your html fine?

Comment: @joyBlanks  that code work only for that JSON, but the columns can have further rows and rows can have further columns

Comment: ok got it. can you help me with a Json I can use for testing?

Comment: @ngShravil.py thank you for your response but I need to make recursively call for nested JSON of rows and columns

Comment: @joyBlanks I shared JSON here, assume that it can multiple rows and columns further https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etadqg

Comment: @ankitchauhan posted a solution is this what you are looking for

Comment: @joyBlanks thank you so much that really works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a component which will generate your html and you can call it recursively

```
@Component({
  selector: "grid",
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="(data | keyvalue)[0].key">
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'rows'">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of data.rows">
          <grid [data]="row"></grid>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'columns'">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let col of data.columns">
          <grid [data]="col"></grid>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
        <grid [data]="data.rows" *ngIf="data.hasRows; else cell"></grid>
        <ng-template #cell>
          <div class="cell">{{ data | json }}</div>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styles: [
    ".row{background-color:red;padding: 5px;}",
    ".col{background-color:green; padding:5px;}",
    ".cell{background-color:cyan;padding:5px;}"
  ]
})
export class GridComponent {
  @Input()
  data: any;
}
```

You can call this grid component from your app/display component like this

```
<grid [data]="jsonData"></grid>
```

This is a head start you can modify the the default switch case to cater to your needs I just did find an attribute `hasRows` in your json if that's true it will recursively call grid component back again.

Hope it helps, Stackblitz for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cqbsg